# Issues with firefox rendering mathjax

Tags: html, css, firefox, mathjax

I am using firefox version 37.0.2 on a Mac. The below image is from the mathjax official site http://www.mathjax.org/#features in HTML/CSS mode.
[image]

Why is it cutting off the integral and parenthesis symbols? Is there some configuration I need to fix this?

Comment: Works fine for me on Fx 37.0.1 on OS X 10.10: [http://i.imgur.com/9qmMNoy.png](http://i.imgur.com/9qmMNoy.png). Just for the sake of it, I updated my Fx to 37.0.2; it still works as before. Must be something on your end, possibly custom user styles or zoom.

Comment: This a known bug which goes back to a bug in Firefox / Gecko https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/1009 we have filed an issue with Mozilla.

Comment: Yes, this looks very familiar to me...

Comment: Note that the issue tracker linked by Peter suggests that the issue is only with locally installed fonts, not web-based fonts.  So one solution would be to disable or remove the STIX fonts that are currently being used by MathJax (use FontBook on the mac to disable all the STIX fonts).